# Using aws dms to sync 2 s3 buckets cross account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-dms

I want to use AWS DMS to sync an S3 bucket in one account to another S3 bucket that belongs to another account.
Can I do set it up to do it automatically?

I tried to look in the documentation but didn't find any explanation about syncing real-time S3 to S3 cross account.

Answer (score 0):

S3 Replication does what you need, without needing to use DMS

> Replication enables automatic, asynchronous copying of objects across Amazon S3 buckets. Buckets that are configured for object replication can be owned by the same AWS account or by different accounts.
> [[ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html)]

Specifically, see the documentation on [Configuring replication when source and destination buckets are owned by different accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-walkthrough-2.html)